# Change html title with jquery multiple times

Tags: jquery, title

I would like to change the document titles multiple times during a website is loaded "contineously", e.g. when outputting data that needs some time to load.

This approch works at any place in the body and multiple times

```
<script>
    $(document).attr('title', 'foo');
</script>
```

But I have to circumvent some Content-Security-Policy protection which disallows pure js in html.

So my idea was

(a) Use a div that will be shown multiple times, e.g.

```
<div class="foo" data-title="1"></div>
```

(b) along with this in jquery

```
$('.foo').on('TRIGGER_NAME_HERE', function() {
    $(document).attr('title', $(this).attr('data-title'));
});
```

I have tried all kind of TRIGGER_NAME_HERE, such as "show" etc. Even a simple "each" on all .foo elements does not work.

The best I found was on("show") but this only applies one time at the end of the page, but not multiple times during page "generation".

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).prop('title', 'test');
```

This is simply a jQuery wrapper for:

```
document.title = 'test';
```

Each time new data is loaded into the DOM of the page, you could write a function and pass a new title string value to it after the response has been received, something like this

```
function changeTitle(newTitle) {
    var title = newTitle;
    $(document).prop('title', title);
}

changeTitle('awesome new title');
```

So whenever a new title is needed, whether it is from an ajax request being successfully returned, or a button is clicked, or a div element has a specific class of 'show' etc, a new value could be passed to the changeTitle function to update the title

Comment: As I wrote I cannot put JS code into the html output (Content-Security-Policy). I have to separate it into js code within a .js file and just an html element which triggers the call of the jquery function.